# How to catch Java exception in c# monodroid

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am working with Xamarin forms and I want to be able to catch specific exceptions and let the rest bubble upwards.

One of those exceptions is the recurring Java.Net.SocketException

But when I write my code like this

```
catch (Java.Net.SocketException)
{

}
```

It does not recognize Java.Net.SocketException

But when I do

```
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

It does work and correctly catches it.

But that doesn't allow me to specifically catch "Java.Net.SocketException"

So how would I got about only catching "Java.Net.SocketException"?

Comment: When you say "and correctly catches it", what happens? You should be able to inspect the type, either through the debugger in Visual Studio or through code such as "e.GetType" where 'e' is the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` in instead of `Java.Net.SocketException`.

You can check the ancestor class of that two class .

You need a class which inherit from `System.Exception`, so that it can be caught.

So you code is like

```
catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException e)
{
}
```